# Android NDK undefined reference during linking

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I'm trying to link an executable created by `ndk-build` to an existing .so library already built with the NDK. Here's my `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/..
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mini_executor
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../..
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mylib
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I'm getting a ton of undefined references when I try to build it, which implies to me that the linking process is not working. Sure enough, if I enable the switch `V=1` on ndk-build, I see the following lines:

```
"Compile++ thumb : mini_executor <= main.cpp
C:/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/mini_executor/main.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I../.. -IC:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include -IC:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/include -IC:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/backward -Ijni/.. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11    -IC:/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/../main.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/mini_executor/main.o 
Executable     : mini_executor
C:/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc --sysroot=C:/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-3/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/mini_executor/main.o C:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/mini_executor
```

The only thing I notice is that nowhere in those commands is there anything about linking to the existing .so file I specified in the .mk file. I've tried using both `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`, but neither one does anything. It doesn't appear as if it's even *trying* to link to the library. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add something like this to your Android.mk file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <path_to_mylib>/libmylib.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The allows your prebuilt static library to be included in your project.

Check out docs/PREBUILTS.html for more information.